# Trouble with DELETE JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

```
DELETE FROM Books INNER JOIN (Classes, Class_Books) ON (Books.ISBN = Class_Books.ISBN AND Class_Books.Class_ID = Classes.Class_ID AND Classes.Term_ID = 63) WHERE Year = '""'
```

Gives Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Replacing DELETE with SELECT it works fine though

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, which will delete records in books that have a Classes.Term_ID = 63.

```
DELETE b FROM Books b
    INNER JOIN Class_Books cb ON b.ISBN = cb.ISBN
    INNER JOIN Classes c ON cb.Class_ID = c.Class_ID  
WHERE Year = '""' 
  AND c.Term_ID = 63
```

Comment: This query times out for someone reason (replacing DELETE with SELECT * it does not though)

Comment: Actually it looks like the whole query is timing out now.. so I'm going to figure the general problem out then reply..

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you say

```
DELETE FROM
```

not

```
DELETE * FROM
```

even though it's

```
SELECT * FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Books 
WHERE ISBN IN (Select Class_Books.ISBN from Class_Books, Classes
               WHERE Class_Books.Class_ID = Classes.Class_ID 
                 AND Classes.Term_ID = 63
              )
AND Year = '""'
```

Comment: This query times out for some reason, even though replacing DELETE with SELECT * it doesnt..

Comment: @babonk, does subquery also times out?

Comment: Actually it looks like the whole query is timing out now.. so I'm going to figure the general problem out then reply

Comment: was a server problem.  your query works, as does the other one..  i'm going to have to accept the other just because it matches my request, but i upvoted you